# where to put while loop with mysqli fetch?

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using mysqli and php to be able to select a column from the database and to also be able to insert data into the database. Now while researching mysqli, I have found out that before checking to see if the number of rows equals to 0, I need to include a `while($stmt->fetch()) {`

Now because I have to blocks of code, one for SELECT and other INSERT, I want to know that does the while fetch loop suppose to wrap round the whole code or does it suppose to wrap round the SELECT block of code and INSERT block of code separately?

UPDATE:

```
    $query = "SELECT TeacherAlias FROM Teacher WHERE TeacherAlias = ?";
       // prepare query
       $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
       // You only need to call bind_param once
       $stmt->bind_param("s",$getid);
       // execute query
       $stmt->execute();
       // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
       $stmt->bind_result($dbTeacherAlias);
       //get number of rows
       $stmt->store_result();
       $numrows = $stmt->num_rows();
       $results = $stmt->fetch_all();


    foreach ($results as $row) {
       if ($numrows == 0){    

           // don't use $mysqli->prepare here
       $query = "SELECT TeacherUsername FROM Teacher WHERE TeacherUsername = ?";
       // prepare query
       $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
       // You only need to call bind_param once
       $stmt->bind_param("s",$getuser);
       // execute query
       $stmt->execute(); 
       // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
       $stmt->bind_result($dbTeacherUsername);
       //get number of rows
       $stmt->store_result();
       $numrows = $stmt->num_rows();
       $results = $stmt->fetch_all();
    }

foreach ($results as $row) {  
       if ($numrows == 0){
                                               // don't use $mysqli->prepare here
       $query = "SELECT TeacherEmail FROM Teacher WHERE TeacherEmail = ?";
       // prepare query
       $stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
       // You only need to call bind_param once
       $stmt->bind_param("s",$getemail);
       // execute query
       $stmt->execute(); 
       // get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
       $stmt->bind_result($dbTeacherEmail);
       //get number of rows
       $stmt->store_result();
       $numrows = $stmt->num_rows();
       $results = $stmt->fetch_all();
}

}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [`mysqli::fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php), which returns an associative array:

```
$results = $stmt->fetch_all();

foreach ($results as $row) {
    // do something...
}
```

Comment: So do I put `$results = $stmt->fetch_all();` below `$numrows = $stmt->num_rows;` in my code and then put the foreach loop above the 
`if ($numrows == 0){` statement and close the loop right at the bottom?

Comment: Think about it: if `$numrows == 0)` you'll have nothing to loop through anyway. In essence, `count($results)` should be the same as `$numrows`. It wouldn't be a bad thing to verify that as a way to test that everything is working properly.

Comment: Ok so what the code is saying is loop through all the fetched rows and then using the if statement, if no rows are found then do something. Does the foreach loop though loop through the whole code, or does there need to be ultiple for each loops. One for SELECT statement query and one for INSERT statement query?

Comment: @user1394925 Yeah, that would be my approach. Either that, or put the loop in your `else` statement.

Comment: Can you please look at my updated code, have I placed the for each loops in the correct places?

Answer (score -2):

```
// if no results found it will return either empty array or null (not sure, check it)
$results = $stmt->fetch_all();

// if $results is an empty array it will not enter the loop
foreach($results as $row) {
    if ($numrows == 0){   // this is never reached if results no results were found
```

Comment: did you seriously just copy an answer?